# how to create new ethereum/solidity contract for each test in javascript/truffle

Tags: javascript, testing, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

### background

I have written an ethereum smart-contract in the [Solidity](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity) language.  In order to test things, I can run a local node using [Ganache](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache) and deploy my contract on it using `truffle migrate`.

### requirements

I want to test my contract using JavaScript.  I want to create a *new* instance of my contract for each test.

### what i've tried

I created a test file `tests/test.js` in my project:

```
const expect = require('chai').expect

const Round = artifacts.require('Round')


contract('pledgersLength1', async function(accounts) {
    it('1 pledger', async function() {
        let r = await Round.deployed()
        await r.pledge(5)
        let len = (await r.pledgersLength()).toNumber()
        expect(len).to.equal(1)
    })
})
contract('pledgersLength2', async function(accounts) {
    it('2 pledgers', async function() {
        let r = await Round.deployed()
        await r.pledge(5)
        await r.pledge(6)
        let len = (await r.pledgersLength()).toNumber()
        expect(len).to.equal(2)
    })
})
```

I run it with `truffle test`.  It's basically [Mocha](https://mochajs.org), but [truffle](https://www.truffleframework.com) defines `artifacts` for you with a JavaScript connection to the smart contracts.

The truffle `contract` function [is almost the same](https://www.truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript#use-contract-instead-of-describe-) as Mocha's `describe` function, with a small change that I don't understand!  I assumed that `contract` would make my contract new each time.  It doesn't.  Perhaps I can use something like `new Round()` instead of `Round.deployed()`, but I just don't know how.

The solution does not *have* to use truffle.

Comment: Are you sure it is not the same contract? On their site they claim that is will be a new contract instance in every `describe` function. How do you know that is the same instance?

Comment: Check this Twitter thread — https://twitter.com/zulhhandyplast/status/1026181801239171072

Comment: @nikosfotiadis I am sure.  The way that I know is probably irrelevant to the question, but if you try to pledge the same amount twice, the contract will error.  So in the example I typed above, I get an error when I expect to not get an error.

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin Yes, using `.new()` instead of `.deployed()` is working like a charm!  That should really be added to the truffle documentation.  Could you post it as an answer?

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I've posted my answer. Appreciate if you can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note that `.new` and `.deployed` are not the same. See what I've found [here](https://twitter.com/zulhhandyplast/status/1026181801239171072).

Follow this example and it should solve your problem:

```
// Path of this file: ./test/SimpleStorage.js
var simpleStorage = artifacts.require("./SimpleStorage.sol");

contract('SimpleStorage', function(accounts) {

  var contract_instance;

  before(async function() {
    contract_instance = await simpleStorage.new();
  });

  it("owner is the first account", async function(){
    var owner = await contract_instance.owner.call();
    expect(owner).to.equal(accounts[0]);
  });

});
```

The `.new` keyword will deploy an instance of your contract in a new context.

But, `.deployed` will actually use the contract that you have deployed earlier i.e. when you are using `truffle migrate` command.

In the context of unit test, it's better to use `.new` so that you will always start with fresh contract.

Comment: This is a great answer and clears the fog over `new()` and `deployed()`.